# Java array seems to change values without being directly modified

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, processing, mergesort

So I am trying to make a mergesort program in java (specifically processing) that steps through the process frame by frame. When it sorted it in 1 frame by going through for loops it seemed to work fine (I didn't test it extensively as it wasn't my goal) but after making the changes to it necessary to have it function, it doesn't seem to want to work correctly.

I haven't tried a whole lot as I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this.

```
merge();

if (i1 < arr.length) {
  if (i2 < arr.length) {
    if (i3 <= i2 + i1) {
      i3++;
    } else {
      i2 += i1 * 2;
      l = i2 + 0;
      r = i2 + i1;
    }
  } else {
    i1 *= 2;
    i2 = 0;
    i3 = 0;
    l = 0;
    r = i1 + 0;

    arr = w.clone();
  }
} else {
  noLoop();
}

void merge() {
  int lMax = i2 + i1;
  int rMax = i2 + i1 * 2;

  if (r < arr.length - 1 && l < arr.length - 1) {
    if ((l <= lMax) && (r >= rMax || arr[l] <= arr[r])) {
      float[] t = arr.clone();
      w[i3] = t[l];
      arr = t.clone();
      l++;
    } else {
      float[] t = arr.clone();
      println(arr[r], t[r], w[i3]);
      w[i3] = t[r];
      println(arr[r], t[r], w[i3]);
      arr = t.clone();
      r++;
      println();
    }
  }
}
```

it should just sort the elements of `arr` but it seems to duplicate them whenever `arr[r] < arr[l]`

Comment: The best thing for you to do would be to step through this with a debugger.  I'm sure you'll be able to see immediately what's going on.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem how could I go about doing that?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: Your IDE will have a debugger built in.  If it's not obvious how to use it, there'll be instructions online somewhere.  Google is your friend.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I stepped through it with the processing debugger but all I got was more confused

Comment: Like others have said, you need to [debug your code](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected? Can you narrow this down to a [mcve]?

Answer (score -1):

I face this type of problem quite a lot in my work, and (if you're using Eclipse, at least, which is what I use) what I do is go into debug mode and put a breakpoint at every single line of code in the section in question and carefully watch the variables, changing the code accordingly. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Using the debugger is a good idea, but this does not answer the question.